# How to adjust ggplot graph regarding color and scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some difficulties to adjust a graph regarding color and scale:

Here some data:

```
#Table 1

date<-c("2015-08-07","2015-08-08","2015-08-09")
A<-c(7268.45,11212.46,12850.15)
B<-c(7009.32,5665.81,16492.11)
C<-c(3582.07,1793.50,5556.42)
D<-c(3653.33,2335.34,2007.50)
df<-data.frame(date,A,B,C,D)


#Table 2

date<-c("2015-08-07","2015-08-08","2015-08-09")
A<-c(7885,8202,11342)
B<-c(7857,8034,11518)
C<-c(3147,3768,4487)
D<-c(3084,3669,4456)
df1<-data.frame(date,A,B,C,D)

#Table 1 / Table 2

date<-c("2015-08-07","2015-08-08","2015-08-09")
A<-c(0.8921115,0.7052290,1.4318554)
B<-c(0.9218072,1.3670397,1.1329704)
C<-c(1.1382491,0.4759820,1.2383374)
D<-c(1.1846077,0.6365059,0.4505162)
df2<-data.frame(date,A,B,C,D)

#Plot:

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df$df = "Table 1"
df1$df = "Table 2"
df2$df = "Table1 / Table2"

bind_rows(df, df1, df2) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -c(date, df)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=as.Date(date), y=value, group=variable))  +
  geom_line(aes(colour = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~df, ncol = 1) +
  scale_x_date() + xlab("")
```

[image]

As one can see the ratio between `Table1 / Table2` is on the same scale as the graphs above. I would like to have `Table1 / Table2` between `0 -2` Additionally I cant really differentiate the colors. Is there a way to make them bold or enhance there perceptibility?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean, but you can set `scales='free_y'` within your `facet_wrap` to have them scaled better?! Or isn't this what you want.

Comment: And you missed the `library(dplyr)` and `library(tidyr)` command ;-)

Comment: @ drmariod, sorry for that...

Comment: and last comment, ;-) the `df2` has only three dates but five values for A,B,C...

Comment: Thank you `scales='free_y'` worked perfectly...do you have any recommendation regarding color...given more variables within a graph one cant differentiate the color anymore. THX

Comment: I posted an answer pointing you to color brewer and also added a concrete example for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `scales='free_y'` within `facet_wrap` function to scale each of the facets separately.

For colouring, check out [color brewer website](http://colorbrewer2.org). There you can find some color schemes which can be used within `ggplot2`.

I like the `Set1` or `Set3` colours a lot. Some example how to integrate are [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_brewer.html)

```
bind_rows(df, df1, df2) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -c(date, df)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=as.Date(date), y=value, group=variable))  +
  geom_line(aes(colour = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~df, ncol = 1) +
  scale_x_date() + xlab("") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette='Set1')
```